# Video hit counter based on video play

Tags: php, video, counter

I am hosting some video on my web and I would like to make a counter based on every video played, is that possible? I have made the counter based on the page load, here's the process:

I pull some of the videos on the front page labeled popular and newest, the counter I have made so far is when one click one of these videos, a page will popped out the counter adds itself in the database.

While these videos are also reside on each user's profile page along with their photos and audios, and of course I can't make the counter on this page based on page load because people who sees the page doesn't necessarily viewed or play the videos. The only idea I've come up with so far is that I would make the counter based on video play, but I don't know how to make one. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  can have the attribute onplay=function(). Have the onplay send a XMLHttpRequest to a page that tallies the video counts.